# Cannot add task ':distZip' as a task with that name already exists. Conflicting task ':distZip' in 'application' & 'distribution' plugins

Tags: gradle

Both 'application' & 'distribution' plugins have ':distZip' task. And it seems you cannot use them together.

Simply including both plugins in build.gradle gives this error:
Cannot add task ':distZip' as a task with that name already exists.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html

As a workaround, I have used ':**installApp**' from '**application**' plugin instead of using ':**installDist**' from '**distribution**' plugin.

This seems like a very simple problem, and I feel there should be an easy way of doing this. I am being new to gradle and groovy, I might be missing something???

Comment: Why You need both plugins at the same time?

Comment: I was using application plug-in to build run scripts (myapp.bat). And I was using distribution plug-in for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Gradle 2.1, however when using the same gradle.build with Gradle 2.9 it works perfectly allowing me to build the application with startScripts and package and deploy it.